# Why aren't the </ br> printing?

Tags: php

Please see the link for the sample php code being printed:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/3ITmRL

Comment: ..because it should be `<br />`

Comment: This is a legit question.  An obvious mistake, but still a real question.

Comment: @jeffmaphone: Yup, shouldn't be closed, but definitely deserving of downvotes for not paying attention...

Comment: I do not see a reason to merit downvotes. Its an easy mistake to make for someone who is new, imo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for `<br />`, not `</ br>` for a line break tag.

Answer (score 3):

You mean `<br />` not `</ br>`.

If you're unfamiliar with markup languages;
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML

Answer (score 2):

You are very close.  You have a typo.  You mean to write the HTML elements as `<br />`, not `</ br>`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `<br />`, not `</ br>`.

Here's a corrected example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/w8r1uN.

Comment: Click on "Source" on your website and you'll see them printed.

Answer (score 1):

You want `<br />` instead of `</ br>`.

(Also, don't put spaces after the / in the close-tags.)

Answer (score -2):

do you mean literally printed on the screen as 
 (text)?  They won't be, your browser will interpret them as actual 
 tags and cause a line break.  Or else they would all appear on the same line.  Or are you trying to say that isn't happening?

Comment: Nope, you're just wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed the code output of the link he provided me.  oh well.

Comment: If `</ br>` *is* giving him line breaks I'd say his browser is broken.

Comment: You can always edit the post, let nice people withdraw the downvotes, then delete your post... (or wait 'till it gets to -3 and get the Peer Pressure badge)

Comment: it's just i saw the link and saw the lines, didn't notice the slash too closely.  oh well.

Comment: No it's okay, I appreciate it =)